# Hide Chrome update notification

Tags: google-chrome, auto-updates

I'm using Google Chrome for [Digital Signage](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-compute-stick-digital-signage.html) and also making it play audio (radio) in a second tab, but since Chrome v60 they removed the flag ([disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636989/google-chrome-autoplay-policy-replaced-disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-pla)) to automatically play sound from an unopened tab.

So I [reverted](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php) back to Chrome v59 and [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update) auto updates. It won't auto update anymore, but after a while it still shows toast popups on the screen which is rather embarrassing. How do I prevent this popup from showing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There a reason you don't just simply disable chrome from being able to automatically update?  If you disable the service, then chrome won't know it isn't the current version, and you would have resolved your problem.

Comment: I make an Intel Compute Stick auto run Chrome which opens 2 tabs (Google Slides and radio), but the radio won't auto play since it's in an unopened tab. I could set the `disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback` flag to true to bypass that, but this has been removed in Chrome v60, that's why I need to revert and properly disable the service

Comment: I would assume you have a method to remote into the device in order to restart the service. Like I said I would just use the administrative template to handle this behavior.  I would even argue there very little reason to even update Chrome, given you are presenting information you created (I assume), and the audio would be a local file (I assume).

Comment: I used to remote into the device with *Chrome Remote Desktop* but that's only possible with the release branch since I'd need to login to Chrome. The device runs Windows 10 Home so remoting with mstsc was out of the question sadly. The audio is an online radio stream (skyradio.nl). But how would the administrative template prevent this update popup?

Comment: Have you even tried my suggestion with regards to disabling the service, and now allowing it to update, before dismissing my suggestion because of the release channel requirement?  I have a feeling it will work.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to disable the service? The "Google Update" plugin does not exist anymore and I have renamed the `Update` folder in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu + Chrome

param that worked for me `--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'`

Full launch command:
`google-chrome --start-fullscreen --incognito --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT' "http://127.0.0.1/" &`